# Fast counting of 2D sub-matrices withing a large, dense 2D matrix?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, matrix

What's a good algorithm for counting submatrices within a larger, dense matrix? If I had a single line of data, I could use a suffix tree, but I'm not sure if generalizing a suffix tree into higher dimensions is exactly straightforward or the best approach here.

Thoughts?

My naive solution to index the first element of the dense matrix and eliminate full-matrix searching provided only a modest improvement over full-matrix scanning.

What's the best way to solve this problem?

```
Example:

Input:

Full matrix:
123
212
421

Search matrix:
12  
21  

Output:
2
```

This sub-matrix occurs **twice** in the full matrix, so the output is 2. The full matrix could be 1000x1000, however, with a search matrix as large as 100x100 (variable size), and I need to process a number of search matrices in a row. Ergo, a brute force of this problem is far too inefficient to meet my sub-second search time for several matrices.

Comment: Do you mean counting **unique** submatrices?

Comment: I second that, you problem statement is not clear. Mebbe you can provide a small example with expected output.

Comment: Do you want _all_ sub-matrices or only those of fixed size, e.g. square in your example? Here's an upper bound on the former: http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~sonya/submatrix.pdf

Comment: Would that match my output at all? No. I'm counting unique sub-matrices of a larger, dense matrix.

Comment: I think he is not counting unique submatrices but counting the number of instances a given matrix appears as a submatrix in the bigger one --- that's how the example works

Comment: Your example doesn't show if you are interested also in those submatrix matches where you need to remove columns or rows in between

Comment: I'll re-edit the example and try to explain better.

Comment: @antti.huima: I misread; thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an algorithms course, I once worked an exercise in which the [Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm) string-search algorithm had to be extended slightly to search for a matching two-dimensional submatrix in the way you describe.

I think if you take the time to understand the algorithm as it is described on Wikipedia, the natural way of extending it to two dimensions will be clear to you. In essence, you just make several passes over the matrix, creeping along one column at a time. There are some little tricks to keep the time complexity as low as possible, but you probably won't even need them.

Searching an N×N matrix for a M×M matrix, this approach should give you an O(N²⋅M) algorithm. With tricks, I believe it can be refined to O(N²).

Comment: Using a hashing mechanism to perform testing with substrings was over **4x** faster in preliminary testing. Hopefully this is efficient enough to avoid more complicated search algorithms.

Comment: I tried Knuth Morris Pratt over Rabin-Karp, but I got similar performance results with my dataset. This really was the quickest and easiest way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Algorithms and Theory of Computation Handbook suggests what is an N^2 * log(Alphabet Size) solution. Given a sub-matrix to search for, first of all de-dupe its rows. Now note that if you search the large matrix row by row at most one of the de-duped rows can appear at any position. Use Aho-Corasick to search this in time N^2 * log(Alphabet Size) and write down at each cell in the large matrix either null or an identifier for the matching row of the sub-matrix. Now use Aho-Corasick again to search down the columns of this matrix of row matches and signal a match where all the rows are present below each other.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a ready answer but here's how I would start:

-- You want very fast lookup, how much (time) can you spend on building index structures?  When brute-force isn't fast enough you need indexes.

-- What do you know about your data that you haven't told us?  Are all the values in all your matrices single-digit integers?

-- If they are single-digit integers (or anything else you can represent as a single character or index value), think about linearising your 2D structures.  One way to do this would be to read the matrix along a diagonal running top-right to bottom-left and scanning from top-left to bottom-right.  Difficult to explain in words, but read the matrix:

```
1234
5678
90ab
cdef
```

as 125369470c8adbef

(get it?)

Now you can index your super-matrix to whatever depth your speed and space requirements demand; in my example key 1253... points to element (1,1), key abef points to element (3,3).  Not sure if this works for you, and you'll have to play around with the parameters to your solution.  Choose your favourite method for storing the key-value pairs: a hash, a list, or even build some indexes into the index if things get wild.

Regards

Mark

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to [template matching.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching)  If motivated you could probably transform your original array with the FFT and drop a log from a brute force search. (N*log(M)) instead of (N*M)