# Efficient way to search a 2d matrix for another matrix of smaller size

Tags: algorithm, search, matrix, language-agnostic, knuth-morris-pratt

I know KMP ([Knuth–Morris–Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm))  is used for one dimensional search. Can it be applied on 2 dimensional array of data? Or is there a more advanced one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can find something in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975386/fast-counting-of-2d-sub-matrices-withing-a-large-dense-2d-matrix) question. You should be able to use KMP with some adaption if you flatten the matrices you are looking for.